# How can I solve the IntelliJ error of running my kotlin file

Tags: android, kotlin, intellij-14, intellij-15

I can't run my project as main class AppKt can not be loaded or found, there is also a problem with a debugger that can be connected. I attached screens of the problem

[Error with the debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQCAi.png)
[Main problem when running the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQCAi.png)

Comment: Can you check your "C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2020.1\captureAgent" directory for 'debugger-agent.jar' & 'debugger-agent-storage.jar' are they present ?

Comment: Yes, they are there

Comment: Is there a red cross sign like this in your IDE near build? Like this : https://i.imgur.com/1CYehLe.png

Comment: It was until I configured AppKt as a the main class in running configurations because it is the only available default main class in such cases, but, as I understand, it can't be found or something(shown in attached pictures to my post)

Comment: So AppKt is your main class now. Do you have the main() method implemented properly in that?

Comment: I can't fully understand what you mean(sorry), but I guess no. It tells me: Error: Could not find or load main class AppKt
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AppKt

Comment: Can you share your AppKt code.

Comment: fun main(){
    println("Hello World")
}

Comment: Late reply, had exam :p,  The code written by you is right. In the question, you should also add images of your project structure. A quick brute solution is to clean-install the IntellijIdea again.